# max and min of $f(x,y)=x^2-\sqrt{e^{(xy)^2}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x,y)=x^2-\sqrt{e^{(xy)^2}-1}$ is continuous on $R^2$ and even.Also $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$ so I consider the first quadrant.
If I study the gradient I don't find stationary points.

If I consider the restriction to y=0: $f(x,0)=x^2$ so the function isn't limited upper

$(0,0)$ can be a stationary point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has no maximum and no minimum:

**Maximum**

If you let $y=0$, the function becomes $f(x, 0)=x^2-\sqrt{e^0-1}=x^2$, which increases without bound as $x$ increases.

**Minimum**

If you set $x=1$ (or any constant other than $0$) the function sumplifies to $f(1, y)=1-\sqrt{e^y-1}$. As $y$ increases without bound, $\sqrt{e^y-1}$ increases, so you are subtracting a bigger and bigger negative number.